# Graphics issue - large white borders in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics, visual-artifacts

For a few weeks I have been seeing these strange white borders around some windows:

[image]

Here a browser window is in the front and the weird frame is not there.

[image]

What could be the cause and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Exactly as you present in the screenshots. The only temporal solution is typing `setsid unity` in the terminal. However, some apps close unexpectedly.